# python re.search error TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, expression

Why would

```
re.search("\.docx", os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
```

yield the following error?

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `os.listdir` returns a `list` but `re.search` wants a string.

The easiest way to do what you are doing is:

```
[f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('.docx')]
```

Or even:

```
import glob
glob.glob('*.docx')
```

Comment: Thanks for being gentle, I just started python today! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`re.search()` expects `str` as the second argument. Refer [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) to know more.

```
import re, os

a = re.search("\.docx", str(os.listdir(os.getcwd())))
if a:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```