# Python 2.7.8: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, expression

I am beginner. I am getting text data from webpage and trying to separate the words by any non-whitespace character. I am completely fail to understand why this is coming. I also met these posts: [python re.search error TypeError: expected string or buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896914/python-re-search-error-typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer) , [pattern matching in malayalam makes TypeError: expected string or buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305330/pattern-matching-in-malayalam-makes-typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer) and many others but could nt able to get rid from this error.

My code function:

```
  def separatewords(self, text):
        splitter = re.compile('\\W*')
        return [s.lower() for s in splitter.split(text) if len(s)>2 and len(s)<20]
```

Error:

```
 TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

**Updated**

here is the output of text from link which is i am passing:

```
t [u'html', u'[if lt IE 7]>   <html class="no-js ie6 lt-ie7 lt-ie8 lt-ie9">   <![endif]', u'[if IE 7]>      <html class="no-js ie7 lt-ie8 lt-ie9">          <![endif]', u'[if IE 8]>      <html class="no-js ie8 lt-ie9">                 <![endif]', u'[if gt IE 8]><!', u' ', u'<![endif]', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'[if (lte IE 8)&(!IEMobile)]>\n    <link href="/static/stylesheets/no-mq.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />\n    \n    \n    <![endif]', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' white shape ', u'\n', u' python blue ', u'\n', u'\n', u'Welcome to Python.org', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Notice:', u' While Javascript is not essential for this website, your interaction with the content will be limited. Please turn Javascript on for the full experience. ', u'\n', u'\n', u'[if lt IE 8]>\n        <div id="oldie-warning" class="do-not-print">\n            <p><strong>Notice:</strong> Your browser is <em>ancient</em> and <a href="http://www.ie6countdown.com/">Microsoft agrees</a>. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade to a different browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to experience a better web.</p>\n        </div>\n        <![endif]', u'\n', u' Sister Site Links ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' Header elements ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Search This Site', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n                                GO\n                            ', u'\n', u'[if IE]><input type="text" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled" size="1" tabindex="4"><![endif]', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' end options-bar ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' ', u' for optional "do-not-print" class ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'# Python 3: Fibonacci series up to n', u"\r\n>>> def fib(n):\r\n>>>     a, b = 0, 1\r\n>>>     while a < n:\r\n>>>         print(a, end=' ')\r\n>>>         a, b = b, a+b\r\n>>>     print()\r\n>>> fib(1000)\r\n", u'0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987', u'\n', u'Functions Defined', u'\n', u'The core of extensible programming is defining functions. Python allows mandatory and optional arguments, keyword arguments, and even arbitrary argument lists. ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'# Python 3: List comprehensions', u"\r\n>>> fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Lime']\r\n>>> loud_fruits = [fruit.upper() for fruit in fruits]\r\n>>> print(loud_fruits)\r\n", u"['BANANA', 'APPLE', 'LIME']", u'\r\n\r\n', u'# List and the enumerate function', u'\r\n>>> list(enumerate(fruits))\r\n', u"[(0, 'Banana'), (1, 'Apple'), (2, 'Lime')]", u'\n', u'Compound Data Types', u'\n', u'Lists (known as arrays in other languages) are one of the compound data types that Python understands. Lists can be indexed, sliced and manipulated with other built-in functions. ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'# Python 3: Simple arithmetic', u'\r\n>>> 1 / 2\r\n', u'0.5', u'\r\n>>> 2 ** 3\r\n', u'8', u'\r\n>>> 17 / 3  ', u'# classic division returns a float', u'\r\n', u'5.666666666666667', u'\r\n>>> 17 // 3  ', u'# floor division', u'\r\n', u'5', u'\n', u'Intuitive Interpretation', u'\n', u'Calculations are simple with Python, and expression syntax is straightforward: the operators ', u'+', u', ', u'-', u', ', u'*', u' and ', u'/', u' work as expected; parentheses ', u'()', u' can be used for grouping. ', u'.', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'# Python 3: Simple output (with Unicode)', u'\r\n>>> print("Hello, I\'m Python!")\r\n', u"Hello, I'm Python!", u'\r\n\r\n', u'# Input, assignment', u"\r\n>>> name = input('What is your name?\\n')\r\n>>> print('Hi, %s.' % name)\r\n", u'What is your name?\r\nPython\r\nHi, Python.', u'\n', u'Quick & Easy to Learn', u'\n', u'Experienced programmers in any other language can pick up Python very quickly, and beginners find the clean syntax and indentation structure easy to learn. ', u' with our Python\xa03 overview.', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'# For loop on a list', u"\r\n>>> numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8]\r\n>>> product = 1\r\n>>> for number in numbers:\r\n...    product = product * number\r\n... \r\n>>> print('The product is:', product)\r\n", u'The product is: 384', u'\n', u'All the Flow You\u2019d Expect', u'\n', u'Python knows the usual control flow statements that other languages speak \u2014 ', u'if', u', ', u'for', u', ', u'while', u' and ', u'range', u' \u2014 with some of its own twists, of course. ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Python is a programming language that lets you work quickly ', u'and integrate systems more effectively. ', u'\n', u'\n', u' end .container ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' Main Content Column ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Get Started', u'\n', u"Whether you're new to programming or an experienced developer, it's easy to learn and use Python.", u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Download', u'\n', u'Python source code and installers are available for download for all versions! Not sure which version to use? ', u'.', u'\n', u'Latest: ', u' - ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Docs', u'\n', u"Documentation for Python's standard library, along with tutorials and guides, are available online.", u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Jobs', u'\n', u"Looking for work or have a Python related position that you're trying to hire for? Our ", u'relaunched community-run job board', u' is the place to go.', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Latest News', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2015-', u'12-07', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2015-', u'12-05', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2015-', u'11-22', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2015-', u'09-13', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2015-', u'09-09', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' end .shrubbery ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Upcoming Events', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2016-', u'03-05', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2016-', u'03-11', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2016-', u'03-12', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2016-', u'04-01', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'2016-', u'04-02', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Success Stories', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' ', u'by Tim Fortenberry', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' end .shrubbery ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Use Python for\u2026', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Web Programming', u':\r\n        ', u', ', u', ', u', ', u', ', u', ', u'\n', u'GUI Development', u':\r\n        ', u', ', u', ', u', ', u', ', u'\n', u'Scientific and Numeric', u':\r\n        ', u'\n', u', ', u', ', u'\n', u'Software Development', u':\r\n        ', u', ', u', ', u'\n', u'System Administration', u':\r\n        ', u', ', u', ', u'\n', u'\n', u' end .shrubbery ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'>>>', u' ', u': The future of Python', u' is discussed here.', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'>>>', u' ', u'\n', u'\n', u'The mission of the Python Software Foundation is to promote, protect, and advance the Python programming language, and to support and facilitate the growth of a diverse and international community of Python programmers. ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' end .container ', u'\n', u' end #content .content-wrapper ', u'\n', u' Footer and social media list ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' end .container ', u'\n', u' ', u' end .main-footer-links ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'<li class="tier-1 element-3"><a href="#"><span class="say-no-more">Website</span> Colophon</a></li>', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'Copyright \xa92001-2016.', u'\n                            \xa0', u'\n                            \xa0', u'\n                            \xa0', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u' end .container ', u'\n', u' end .site-base ', u'\n', u'\n', u' end #touchnav-wrapper ', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'[if lte IE 7]>\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/plugins/IE8-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>\n    \n    \n    <![endif]', u'\n', u'[if lte IE 8]>\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/plugins/getComputedStyle-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>\n    \n    \n    <![endif]', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n']
```

**Update2**
my function for extracting text:

```
def getTtextonly(self, soup):
        url = soup
        #url = "http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/"
        html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

        # kill all script and style elements
        for script in soup(["script", "style","a","<div id=\"bottom\" >"]):
            script.extract()    # rip it out

        text = soup.findAll(text=True)
        return text
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you passing `text` to `sepratatewords` ?..Can you post an example with results?..and expected output?

Comment: yeh i ve added the update

Comment: That does not look like a `string` ?...it's a list of `string` instead

Comment: i ve extracted it from webpage and this is what i am getting.....

Comment: link from wherre i am extracting: https://www.python.org/

Comment: or i am doing wrong while extracting text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the text example you posted, you are passing a list of `string` instead of a single `string`, so here is a fix to your code:

```
def separatewords(self, text):
    splitter = re.compile('\\W*')
    return [s.lower() for t in text for s in splitter.split(t) if 2 < len(s) < 20]
```

Comment: Please, include more details to clarify your question...it's not clear what you want here..

Comment: yeh thnx a lot i am getting no error and it is proceeding further. thnx a lot

Comment: by the way i also have added funtion getTextonly(.....). Am i doing wrong there while extracting text?

Answer (score 0):

The `text` you're passing to `separatewords` isn't a string or buffer.

Comment: i ve added the value of text in the update can u see?